# Apparently i have to re-buy minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]Ok, So I used to have Minecraft on my old PC, but I switched to my laptop, I logged back into my mojang account so I could re-download it, but, it says I have to buy it again? Am I doing something wrong or do I really have to buy it again?

I Have looked all over other websites but nobody could help, so hopefully someone on here knows for sure how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Is this Windows 10? Because that launcher looks outdated

Comment: did you have a mojang or microsoft login

Comment: On top of what Topcode said, did you have a Legacy Minecraft account or a Mojang account?

Comment: If you can find the email you got when buying the game, with purchase ID in it, Mojang support will be able to resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi sorry i have not been checking this but yes i do have a microsoft login but when i entered my details it said account does not exist

Answer (score -2):

Hello I am Minecraft Specialist Joseph Casey Speaking. Ok so no. Do not rebuy it. You can log back into it on any platform including mobile, Console, Ect. See if you have your password/Username typed incorrect before you even think about rebuying it. If it is correct, Consult Mojang about it, they can tell you more.

Comment: that is factually incorrect, and badly spelled

Comment: Well it depends, What would you be wanting to log on to? Microsoft, or mojang? If its Mojang account for PC, then yes, you can log into any platform. I have done it on PC, PS4, and Mobile.

Comment: no, i cant log into my mojang account on a ps4 and download minecraft, i would still have to buy minecraft on that platform. its not the problem at hand either way. similarly, i had to buy minecraft on my switch and THEN could login to my account. you can login to any (most) platforms with it, however it isnt how you obtain the game last i checked

Comment: @Topcode you can log into a Mojang account anywhere with a browser and even download it and login on a computer for no charge

Comment: @Topcode that's not what I said, read it again

Comment: @Penguin ah i see, although thats still sorta wrong

Comment: @Topcode why is it wrong?

Comment: @Penguin java edition is not the only form of minecraft supported on pc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119286/discussion-between-penguin-and-topcode).